# Show that every proper subgroup of $G := \{x \in \mathbb{C} : ∃n \in \mathbb{N}, x^{p^n} = 1\}$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

> **Problem:** Let $p$ be a positive prime integer. Consider the set under multiplication $$G := \{x \in \mathbb{C} : ∃n \in \mathbb{N}, x^{p^n}
> = 1\}.$$
>   Show that every proper subgroup of $G$ is finite.

I know that $G$ must be infinite or else, assume that $|G|=m$. We can choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p^n>m$. The polynomial $x^{p^n}-1$ has precisely $p^n$ distinct roots which belong to $G$. Thus, $m=|G|\geq p^n$, leads to a contradiction. However, I have no idea to prove that every proper subgroup of $G$ must be finite.

Help me, thank you so much!

Comment: This may help: http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/an-infinite-group-whose-proper-subgroups-are-all-finite/

Comment: $x^{p^n}-1$ has finitely many roots which form a cyclic group. Let $H$ be your subgroup, if it contains one root of $x^{p^n}-1$ which is not a root of $x^{p^{n-1}}-1$ then it contains all of them.  Thus if $H$ is infinite then for every $n$ it contains one root of $x^{p^n}-1$ which is not a root of $x^{p^{n-1}}-1$  which means $H $ contains the roots of all the $x^{p^n}-1$ so that $H=G$.